# How to paste values from clipbord to a listview javafx?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm trying to implement a code that will allow a user to copy values from a tableview and paste the values in a Listview in javafx. The first part I've succeeded in implementing it, i.e I've created a context menu(Copy) in the tableview and and got the value to the clipboard.

here is the code

```
    public void allowCopyAndPaste(){
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Copy");
item.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        //ObservableList rowList = (ObservableList) scheduledCitizenTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        StringBuilder clipboardString = new StringBuilder();

   

            for (citizen cell : scheduledCitizenTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
                if (cell == null) {
                    cell = null;
                }
                clipboardString.append(cell.getCitizenName());
                clipboardString.append('\t');
            }
            clipboardString.append('\n');

       
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

        content.putString(clipboardString.toString());
        Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
        System.out.println("testing paste"+content.size());
        
    }
});
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.getItems().add(item);
scheduledCitizenTable.setContextMenu(menu);
```

}

Now in the last part of the problem, i would like to paste the value obtained from the clipboard to a listview
below is the code for the listview

```
public class EmployeeScheduledController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private JFXListView<String> employeeS;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

Overall I just need to paste the values from the clipboard in the listview. Any help?

## Updates

I'found a light in the tunnel, so what i've done now is set the Clipboard to public static and then when the listbox window opens Set the values obtained in the clipboard to the the listbox as

```
employeeS.getItems().add(citizen.content.getString());
```

note that citizen is the object of the class where there is the table and employeeS is the listbox

Difficulties that I'm having now is how to pouplate each individual row copied from the tableview ?

```
content = "Tom Jones James Alfred George"
```

for example let say I've copied the content from the table now i want to put it in the listview, it will put the entire string as if the cells in the tableview were concatinated together, I need to put for example Tom in listview of index 0 ,Jones in Listview of index 1 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done the hard part so far btw. 
So, since you are capable of copying all the stuff, the pasting and splitting the content is quite easy.
All you have to do is split the content string from the spaces. You can achieve this by doing,

```
String[] names = content.split("\\s");
```

now you can populate your list using a foreach loop

```
for(String name : names){
   //put name into listView
}
```

**EDIT**

To avoid name collisions, it is better to append a symbol or a number (or some other thing). So in my case, after a name, I would append '&' sign to the clipboard string. So it would look like,

```
clipboardString.append(cell.getCitizenName());
clipboardString.append("&");
```

So after that, using the same logic given above you can split it like,

```
String[] names = content.split("&");
```

and then you can use the foreach loop to populate your listview

Comment: That's what i thought but what if i have a name like "John Smith" ? this logic will failed

Comment: Well it's the way you do it, in your code, you append a tab ("\t") after each citizen name. Hence you're having spaces between each name. So i recommend you to have any other symbol after a citizen name, and split from that symbol.